# Installing gitorious issue

Tags: gitorious, git-daemon

I am struggling with the installation of gitorious (on an Ubuntu 12.04 distribution) on my local server following this tutorial : http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/setting_up_gitorious_on_your_own_server

After fixing some some config, I went running this command : `env RAILS_ENV=production /etc/init.d/git-daemon start`, I keep on having this message `Starting git-daemon: FAILURE!!!`, without finding any log message. After googling, I found it could be a config problem in the /etc/init.d/git-daemon config file : I put it [here](http://www.2shared.com/document/2w9aV5zB/config-daemon.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Can't say I can pinpoint the problem. Can you get any messages out of `dmesg | tail`?
I remember having some problems with the `git-daemon`, and I think they boiled down to some problem with ActiveMQ. Unfortunately, I can't remember how I fixed it.

There also seems to be a pretty neat, concise install script that streamlines the setup process for Ubuntu 12.04: https://gist.github.com/4236547

PS: You might want to get an account on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to make your config file more easily accessible.